# Hapi.js: "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: typescript, api, webpack, hapi.js

I'd like to write an API in Typescript with Hapi.js and webpack transpiling and bundling the whole application.

unfortunately when I create the simplest Hapi server (or even create a server instance) I get the following error:

```
exports = module.exports = internals.Response = class extends Http.ServerResponse {
                                                                   ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

```

my Hapi version is ^17.5.4 and the typings ^17.0.19, both should be the most recent versions.

**index.ts**

```
import {Server, ServerOptions} from 'hapi';

const options: ServerOptions = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '9000'
}

const server = new Server(options); // instsantiating the server causes the error
```

**webpack.config.ts**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: [
             "node_modules",
             path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
        ],
    },
    module: {
         rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
         ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty'
    }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "lib": ["ES2015", "dom"],
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "*/src/**/*.ts",
        "*/src/**/*.tsx",
        "*/tests/**/*.ts",
        "*/index.ts",
        "tsd.d.ts"
      ]
}
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hapi.js has an indirect reference to Node's built-in `http` module, and by default, Webpack redirects references to Node built-in modules to its browser-compatible replacement modules, which may not provide all the functionality of the Node built-in modules.  In this case, the replacement for `http` has no `ServerResponse` export, so you get a runtime error.  (It's unfortunate that this isn't caught at build time, I assume because `ts-loader` is not smart enough to redirect TypeScript to the typings for the browser-compatible modules.)

Assuming you intend to run your bundle on Node, you need to add `target: 'node'` to the Webpack configuration to tell Webpack to allow the generated bundle to use Node built-in modules without redirection.  See [the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/).

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the great explanation and the link to the docs, matt! a tiny change to the config, which had a great impact ;)

Comment: have you found a way out of this? i am facing this issue